# c++ missing construction and destruction of an object

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor, copy-constructor

The following code:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void print(string a) { cout << a << endl; }
void print(string a, string b) { cout << a << b << endl; }
 
class A {
    public:
    string p;
    A() { print("default constructor"); }   
    A(string a){ p = a; print("string constructor ", p); }
    A(const A& o) { print("copy constructor"); }
    A (A&& o) { print("move constructor"); }
    A& operator=(const A& o) { print("copy assignment"); return *this; }
    A& operator=(const A&& o) { cout << "move assignment to:" << p << " from:" << o.p << endl; return *this; }
    ~A() { print("destructor ", p); }
};

A operator+(const A& a, const A& b) { 
    cout << "add" <<endl; 
    A c("f"); 
    return c;
}
    
A f(A& a, A& b, A& c) {
    A d("e");
    d = a+b+c;
    print("after add");
    return d;
}

int main() {
    A a("a"); A b("b"); A c("c");
    A whereDidThisGo {f(a,b,c)};
    print("end");
}
```

has the following output:

```
string constructor a
string constructor b
string constructor c
string constructor e
add
string constructor f
add
string constructor f
move assignment to:e from:f
destructor f
destructor f
after add
end
destructor e
destructor c
destructor b
destructor a
```

---

Process exited after 0.06744 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .

**Where is the construction/destruction of the whereDidThisGo variable defined in main?**

Comment: Look up "NRVO". Also the move assignment should use a non-const reference parameter.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat is right. Although a const rvalue reference is possible, it's almost always a mistake. The point of taking an rvalue reference is usually that you're going to modify what it refers to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where is the construction/destruction of the whereDidThisGo variable defined in main?

You do not see the ouptut for this due to named return value optimization(aka NRVO).

> it's not a good optimization for people like me who are trying to learn constructors

You can **disable** this NRVO by providing the `-fno-elide-constructors` flag to the compiler. [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2ThZ5k2ssoXzhGxM).

---

Also, note that in your example the `A::operator=(const A&&)` should instead be:

```
//-----------vv------->no need for const  here
A::operator=(A&&)
```

Answer (score 1):

TIL about [NRVO](http://stupefydeveloper.blogspot.com/2008/10/c-rvo-and-nrvo.html), it's not a good optimization for people like me who are trying to learn constructors haha.

Thank you for the answers, yes the move assignment should be a non-const pointer, I simply overlooked it.

Comment: You can disable this optimization by providing the `-fno-elide-constructors` to the compiler. See example(demo link) in my answer below.

Comment: I doubt HolyBlackCat and JerryCoffin will write answers, since they replied in comments, so please mark one of the answers as "accepted" so the whole question is marked as done. 'Anoop Rana's seem fine, as it mentions the way to distable NRVO - but that's probably compiler-specific.